# Enable Scriptlet Does Not Exist

Tags: centos, scl

I'm trying to run the below but it keeps coming back with this error `warning: /opt/rh/devtoolset-4//enable scriptlet does not exist!`.

```
yum install epel-release
yum install centos-release-scl cmake3 hwloc-devel libmicrohttpd-devel openssl-devel git screen nano
yum install devtoolset-4-gcc*
scl enable devtoolset-4 bash
```

I've tried uninstalling all the packages and reinstalling them to no avail, any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

The `devtoolset-#-runtime` package needs to be installed as well.

```
yum install devtoolset-#-runtime
```

or

```
rpm -Uvh $(repoquery --location devtoolset-#-runtime)
```

(please replace `#` with the version)

Then you should see the enable scriptlet in the appropriate directory.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
#yum reinstall devtoolset-4-runtime
```